# Hazelcast, recovering a MessageListener member after termination due to message loss

Tags: hazelcast, circular-buffer, hazelcast-imap, reliable-message-delivery, splitbrain

We have a `ReliableMessageListener` that synchronizes some data structures that it holds across the cluster by the `onMessage` implementation.

The cluster is composed of three nodes. We noticed that one of the topics gets out of sync, and had been terminated due to message loss, detected by the ring-buffer, as we get a "`Terminating MessageListener, ... Reason: Underlying ring buffer data related to reliable topic is lost`" exception. What happens is that this node is still up, but this specific listener does not get events/messages from the other two nodes, while they do get those from it.

We get to a de-facto split-brain for this specific topic.

Our message listener is configured as `isLossTolerant = false`, and `isTerminal = false`.

I am trying to understand what is considered to be a good strategy for handling such a scenario and recovering from it.

For example, is that a good practice to try and subscribe this topic again?
Is that a good practice to send a message for clearing the data from the other nodes in the cluster? Will they even get the message after the ring-buffer got out of sync?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message `Reason: Underlying ring buffer data related to the reliable topic is lost` means that the data you are trying to read is not available anymore because it was overwritten by newer data in the underlying Ringbuffer - your producer is likely faster than your consumers.

When such a situation occurs the ReliableTopic is still usable, and you can register a new listener.

To prevent the situation from occurring you can either increase the size of the underlying ringbuffer (provide ringbuffer config with same name as the reliable topic) or configure `TopicOverloadPolicy`. See [documentation](https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/5.0/data-structures/reliable-topic#slow-consumers) for details.

Comment: Hi. If I examine the flow of handling exception in Hazelcast (3.12) I see that a StaleSequenceException is most likely to "indicate that the reader was too slow", and an IllegalArgumentException "may indicate that an entire partition or an entire ringbuffer was lost". The message that I got is logged in the IllegalArgumentException  flow.